# Adding document in Couchbase and missing JSON body

Tags: rest, postman, couchbase

I am trying to use Couchbase REST API to add a document to the existing documents. I am just testing this in Postman while writing on the code.

```
POST:

http://<ip>:8091/pools/default/buckets/<bucketname>/docs/testdoc1?rev=1

Headers:

Accept: application/json
Authorization : xxxxx

Body:

Raw JSON (application/json)
{
  "Name": "xxx",
  "Address": "yyy",
  "Phone number": "xxxx",
  "Badge": "yyy",
  "BadgeType": "xxx"
}
```

When I send above in Postman, It is adding this new doc. under couchbase documents/bucket, but on the body field it shows like, "Binary Document, base64 not available"

I tried even from my html code, but json body didn't receive at couchbase end.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="submit" value="Start" onclick="submit()">

<script type="text/javascript">
var params = {
  "Name": "xxx",
  "Address": "yyy",
  "Phone number": "xxxx",
  "Badge": "yyy",
  "BadgeType": "xxx"
} 
    function submit() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                alert(xhr.response);
            }
        }
        xhr.open('post', 'http://<ip>:8091/pools/default/buckets/<buckname>/docs/testdochtml?rev=1', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + 'xxxxxxx');

        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    }
</script>

<p>Click on the submit button.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone guide me why is that JSON not going to couchbase in a correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: as far as I know, **this endpoint is not supported** and it is not documented. If you see somewhere that it *is* supported, let me know, because I think that needs corrected. You should use one of the SDKs (Java, .NET, Node, etc) instead.

**That being said**, I was able to get it working via Postman. You can't just send raw JSON as the document. You need to POST encoded form data. One of the values this endpoint expects is "value", which contains the encoded JSON document.

Here's an example of what I did (I called my bucket "so"):

```
POST /pools/default/buckets/so/docs/testdoc2 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ba87ef4e-4bba-42b4-84da-ae775b26dbcb
value=%7B%0A%09%22Name%22%3A+%22xxx%22%2C%0A%09%22Address%22%3A+%22yyy%22%2C%0A%09%22Phone+number%22%3A+%22xxxx%22%2C%0A%09%22Badge%22%3A+%22yyy%22%2C%0A%09%22BadgeType%22%3A+%22xxx%22%0A%7D%0A
```

Note that value above is just the URL-encoded JSON from your question (Postman encoded it for me, and Postman must have added the cache-control header on its own too, because I did not specify that):

[image]

Comment: Hi Mathew, thanks for the answer. I didn't get how to post encoded form data in Postman? Please give me some sample reference. Also, I have tried through sample HTML code, (please refer question to see the code pasted), but didn't working. Could you please see and let me know if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: It will not work from HTML because of CORS, and you can't turn that off. The REST API for Couchbase Server is not designed to be called from client-side JavaScript. You might want to look into Sync Gateway instead.

Comment: Here's a video of it working in Postman, but AGAIN, this is not something you should be doing. You should be using an SDK to do this instead - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RZ4LqZw8QQ

Comment: Thank you and Appreciate it.